# What django model field should I use to store a duration of time less than a full day?

Tags: django, django-models

I am storing the duration of time for a time keeping system. No need to store timezone info.

Initially I decided to store the value a a `DecimalField` because there was a restriction of closest 15 minutes meaning the decimal would work as it would be restricted to `0.25` increments.

Eventually I decided that is no good as what if in future the `15 minute` increments requirement is removed.

- I do not need to store seconds
- I need to report on totals at the end of the month

So I pretty much have these 3 data types and I am struggling to choose which would be best.

- [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#timefield)
- [PositiveIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield)
- [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#durationfield)

Comment: It seems that `DurationField` is what you are looking for. What is the problem?

Comment: It depends on the type of queries you want to do.